# How does this optimization problem work?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

$$
\begin{split}
\max_{\beta, \epsilon, M} M\\
\mathrm{subject\ to}\\ \sum_{j=1}^p \beta_j^2 &= 1\\
y_i\left(\beta_0 + \sum_{k=1}^p \beta_k x_{ik}\right) &\ge M (1- \epsilon_i),
\quad \epsilon_i \ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i \le C,
\end{split}
$$
where $C \ge 0$ is a tuning parameter.
In this problem,

- $x_i$ denotes the training sample (Input)
- $y_i$ denotes the training observation(Output).
- $y_i \in [-1,1] $

The above optimization problem is to choose the best separating hyperplane for a support vector classifier. But I have absolutely no clue how it works. can anyone explain this? Thanks.

Comment: Please include the formulas via [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) rather than an image. Images are not searchable. Also, what is $y_i$ and $x_{ij}$?

Comment: Please tell us what the letters mean.  What are the $x_i, y_i?$

Comment: @saulspatz Added to the original post.

Comment: Are the $y_i$ all equal to 0 or 1?

Comment: @saulspatz Nope, it's either -1 or 1.

Comment: Please add this information to the problem statement.  People browsing the questions may not read the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz Done.

Comment: This seems to be a very nice discussiion: http://web.mit.edu/6.034/wwwbob/svm-notes-long-08.pdf